# How to serialize file without host?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on my Django (DRF) app.

I have a user avatar

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', blank=True)
    ...
```

I want to serialize avatar field:

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    avatar = serializers.FileField(use_url=False, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            'avatar',
            ...
        ]
```

Current result is `"avatar": "avatars/ZZZ.png"`

How can I get `"avatar": "media/avatars/ZZZ.png"` ??? (what is the proper way)

Saved file location is http://localhost:6060/media/avatars/<file_name>.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with image field serialized. Below is my solution, and don't know if there is a better way.
You can override the `to_representation` method of your serializer to achieve it as shown below.

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    avatar = serializers.FileField(use_url=False, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            'avatar',
            ...
        ]

    def to_representation(self, instance):
         resp = super().to_representation(instance)
         resp['avatar'] = f'media/{resp["avatar"}'
         return resp
```

Comment: Thank you, but it looks like a workaround. And it's odd that we don't have 'media' in the url by default

Comment: Yeah. But to override default data, we need to override to_representation. as the name suggests it is just altering the representational layer. Also one thing to note, this will run on all the instances which are being serialized

Comment: The code isn't working
```AttributeError: 'CustomUserSerializer' object has no attribute 'avatar' ```

Comment: updated the code. please check

Comment: We should use resp['avatar'] instead

Comment: yeah right.. modified and tested. it is working now